Flutter Firebase dynamic links with custom dynamic parameters?
I'm trying to open an external link that should either redirects me to a product page inside my flutter app if the app is installed, or redirects me to the store app page if the app is not installed.
For that I tried to use Firebase dynamic links, but the issue is that the url should contain a dynamic parameter (id) that changes based on the product.
Is it possible to achieve this using flutter firebase dynamic links? I am able to read the dynamic link and extract params from it but params that I manually pass inside the firebase console.
I just need to understand the logic that I need to follow to achieve this, thanks in advance.
NB: The documentation doesn't contain dynamic params parsing as far as I have seen

Firebase Dynamic Links is deprecated, for further information see here.

I want to use it as a temporary solution for now, until I find an alternative. Do you think I should use Branch.io instead?

I also have to find another solution because I use FDL in some projects. I have not really started looking into the possible solutions but I bookmarked an article about this, maybe it helps you, see here.
